# Iterating GCD function in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, greatest-common-divisor

I am using this JavaScript function to determine the GCD of two values obtained from input fields:

```
Math.GCD = function(first,second) {
    if (first < 0) first = -first;
    if (second < 0) second = -second;
    if (second > first) {var temp = first; first = second; second = temp;}
    while (true) {
        first %= second;
        if (first == 0) return second;
        second %= first;
        if (second == 0) return first;
    }
};
```

I would like to extend this to compute the GCD of three numbers, if the user enters a number into a third input field (otherwise, the user will input two and calculate as per this function). Being relatively new to JavaScript, I am not sure how to extend this function for three values. Can anyone help?

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/1/

Also, I would like to determine the LCM in a likewise fashion, as observed in the fiddle, but, again, I am unsure how to extend the given function. Please, help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extend the function for any number of parameters `n`, just loop `n-1` times over an array of parameters.

This is because mathematically `gcd(a,b,c) = gcd(a,gcd(b,c))`

Usage: `var GCDresult = Math.GCD([16,222,70]); // result: 2`.

```
// numbers is an array of numbers: ex. [15,20,35,170]
Math.GCD = function(numbers) {
  for (var i = 1 ; i < numbers.length ; i++){
    // take the next number for GCD with the first, 
    // and store the result back in the first.
    numbers[0] = twogcd(numbers[0], numbers[i]);
  }
  return numbers[0];

  // following is your original GCD function
  function twogcd(first, second) {
    if (first < 0) first = -first;
    if (second < 0) second = -second;
    if (second > first) {var temp = first; first = second; second = temp;}
    while (true) {
        first %= second;
        if (first == 0) return second;
        second %= first;
        if (second == 0) return first;
    }
   }
};
```

Your JSFiddle, updated for GCD case is [here](https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/2/).

Comment: I've changed the fiddle to include the user inputs and a calculation button, but I can't figure out how the exclude the third input, should the user leave it blank. I've tried using an `if-else` statement with `numbers.length` but that was a bust (at least, I can't get it to work). Here's the updated fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/13/

Comment: @newbie2015 If you want to let the user give only partial input just add a contidion before the call to `twogcd`: `if (numbers[i] || numbers[i] === 0)
      numbers[0] = twogcd(numbers[0], numbers[i]);` . Next time, please ask another question.

Comment: Apologies. Also, this doesn't seem to work! The script crashes. https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/23/

Comment: Condition has to be `numbers[i] || numbers[i] === 0` because if the user left a blank box then numbers[i] === undefined. `numbers[i]` is `false` also in case that `number[I] === 0` so you have to include `numbers[i] === 0` in the condition. Here's the JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/44/.

Answer (score 0):

You can have something that can accept any number of arguments by using the same function.

And you may extend it too : [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/tjj7won4/3/)

```
Math.GCDe = function() {
    var result = arguments[0];
        for (var i=1;i<arguments.length;i++) 
        result = this.GCD(result,arguments[i]);
    return result;
}
```